# How to Set flash intensity during analysis using camerax java

Tags: android-camerax

I am trying to do some image analysis using android camera x java. during this analysis the flashlight should be on and the object should be relatively close to the camera.  on some devices this is ok but for some devices the flashlight is so bright the image is really white.

i was searching for a solution and found that camera2 camera manager has a function to start flash with intensity [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(java.lang.String,%20int)) but i found nothing related to camera x all i can do is enable/disable torch

here is a snippet of the code i am using to bind preview

```
 private void bindPreview(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(mCameraView.getSurfaceProvider());
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                        .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
                        .build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
            @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
            @Override
            public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
                //ANALYSIS DONE HERE

                imageProxy.close();
            }
        });
        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis,preview);
        camera.getCameraControl().enableTorch(true);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think CameraX supports it right now. The API was added in API 33 so it won't be available on most of the devices anyway. If you wish to see the feature in CameraX, please file a feature request here and the team will look into it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=618491&template=1257717

Comment: is there any way lets say use camera manager (camera2) to set the flash intensity then use camera x? or shall i make all my code use camera 2?

Comment: Not at the moment, unfortunately. :(